# You are providing a function without a theme in the context. One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I am creating a Navbar in a Project. In my Project I use

- mui/icons-material: ^5.2.5
- mui/material: ^5.2.6
- mui/styles: ^5.2.3

###### Now My folder structure is

- Root.jsx

  - Navbar.jsx
  - styles.js

###### I am having an error of

```
The `styles` argument provided is invalid. 
You are providing a function without a theme in the context. 
One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider.
```

###### I have tried to fix with

- Add ThemeProvider at Root.jsx
- Remove from Root.jsx & Add at Navbar.jsx
- & Others

**Note:** I don't know Material UI. Please help me to get out from this error. Here I am providing my code.

###### Code

- Code of `Root.jsx`

```js
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from './Navbar'

const Root = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
        </>
 )}
export default Root
```

- Code of `Navbar.jsx`

```js
import React from 'react'
import { AppBar, Menu, MenuItem, Toolbar, Typography, IconButton, Badge } from '@mui/material'
import { ShoppingCart } from '@mui/icons-material'
import useStyles from './styles'
import Logo from '../../images/logo.png'

const Navbar = () => {

    const classes = useStyles()

    return (
        <>
            <AppBar className={classes.appBar} position='fixed' color='inherit'>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Typography className={classes.title} variant='h6' color='inherit'>
                        <img className={classes.image} alt='Tech Cart' src={Logo} height='25px' />
                        Tech Cart
                    </Typography>
                    <div className={classes.grow} />
                    <div className={classes.button}>
                        <IconButton aria-label='Show cart products' color='inherit'>
                            <Badge badgeContent={2} color='secondary'>
                                <ShoppingCart />
                            </Badge>
                        </IconButton>
                    </div>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </>
    )
}
export default Navbar
```

- Code of `style.js`

```js
import {
    makeStyles
} from '@mui/styles'
import {
    alpha
} from '@mui/material/styles'

const drawerWidth = 0;

export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
    appBar: {
        boxShadow: 'none',
        borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
            marginLeft: drawerWidth,
        },
    },
    title: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        display: 'flex',
        textDecoration: 'none',
    },
    image: {
        marginRight: '10px',
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            display: 'none',
        },
    },
    grow: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    search: {
        position: 'relative',
        borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
        backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
        },
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
        marginLeft: 0,
        width: '100%',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: 'auto',
        },
    },
    searchIcon: {
        padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
        height: '100%',
        position: 'absolute',
        pointerEvents: 'none',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    inputRoot: {
        color: 'inherit',
    },
    inputInput: {
        padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
        // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
        paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)}px)`,
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
        width: '100%',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
            width: '20ch',
        },
    },
}));
```

Comment: try this: 
import {useStyles} from './styles'

Comment: I already do it at `Navbar.jsx` @yanirmidler

Comment: yes but you didnt put it in { }

Comment: After it, I am having `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _styles__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useStyles) is not a function`

Answer (score 5):

I also ran into this issue. These are the steps I followed to solve the issue:

1. Add following import in the component that will use mui:
   [import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf9ZN.png)
2. Next, create a theme.
   [createTheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mLQD.png)
3. Wrap the component within Themeprovider and pass the theme to it:
   [themeprovider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24MWu.png)

Answer (score 2):

try this in your Root component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import {createTheme} from '@mui/material';
import {ThemeProvider} from '@mui/styles';
const Root = () => {
const theme = createTheme()
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Navbar />
        </ThemeProvider>
 )}
export default Root
```

you can find more details in this link https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/

Comment: correct import is this

import {ThemeProvider} from '@mui/styles';

Answer (score 1):

You need to use createTheme function from mui, https://mui.com/customization/theming/ Here you can watch examples. MakeStyles is used to style a specific component, but not the whole application.

so you need to do something like this:

> ```
> const theme = createTheme({
>   //here you set palette, typography ect...
> })
> ```

Then you wrap your whole application in ThemeProvider like this...

> ```
> <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
>   //Your application
> </ThemeProvider>
> ```

and then, when you use makeStyles({theme}) your theme object will have your described theme values.

Comment: But I just need to style a specific component `Navbar`. So what about it?

Comment: The point of ThemeProvider, is that every component in Mui will have access to the styles. For example, primary color in Mui by default is blueish, maybe you want it to be orange or something else, you specify it and in createTheme function, and after that, if you set your NavNar color o primary, it will be orangeish. Send me a codeSandbox example, I will write the code, it will be clearer to you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I do codeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-ibzzy). It's don't show sometime error on sandbox but it's show in local. but the sandbox don't show the navbar. One more thing that I have note by trying later, in my `style.js` I have some code with `theme` & when I do comment out them then it show me navbar with something missing which I do comment out. Please help me to get out from this error.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my ThemeProvider in the MainLayout and then received this error message, then i took it in Index component as the parent of the MainLayout then it has been solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To throw more light to @MAHDI's Answer

Do this:

```
import { ThemeProvider, makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'
import { createTheme, createTheme } from '@mui/material'
```

Create a function within your component wrapper:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    ...... jsx/js style properties  .......
}));

 function App(){

      const theme = createTheme();

      return (
               <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    .....  Your children components  ....
               </ThemeProvider>
      );
 }
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who are migrating MUI from v4 to v5, they might face this error.

Update your imports as shown below:

```js
import { ThemeProvider, makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'
import { createTheme, createTheme } from '@mui/material'
```

Comment: did the same thing but still get the same error